# time interval between messages published on a topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I want to calculate time interval between messages that are published on a topic. The topic is /aruco_poses and of type aruco_mapping/ArucoMarker. It has std_msgs/Header field with stamp containing sec and nsec. But I don't know how to access nsec field from the topic. Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280664/time-interval-between-messages-published-on-a-topic/) by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this with ROS times and durations: [roscpp](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Time_and_Duration_Arithmetic), [rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Converting_Time_and_Duration_instances). You will have to save the previous message, then when you get a new one you can do `double elapsed_time = (msg.header.stamp - prev_msg.header.stamp).toSec()` (rospy has similar logic).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0